# Mathematics behind the thermodynamic arrow of time

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, arrow-of-time

Since the thermodynamic arrow of time is related to the second law of thermodynamics, how can I (mathematically) describe the operation of the operator $\hat{T}:t \mapsto -t$ on said law ? In other words, how to generally mathematically describe the effect of a reversal of time on the second law of thermodynamics ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Voting to re-open. The question now focusses on a single issue - and it has a straightforward answer.

Comment: @gandalf61 Could you provide your answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

The entropy version of the second law of thermodynamics does not actually define a particular direction for time. It simply says that there is a temporal asymmetry about entropy - if we move in one direction in time then entropy increases, and conversely if we move in the other direction then entropy decreases.

Conventionally we call the direction in which entropy decreases "the past", and the direction in which entropy increases we call "the future". But this is arbitrary - we could reverse the direction in which we measure time if we wanted to. So replacing $t$ by $-t$ has no effect on the second law of thermodynamics - it has no more effect than if we were to reverse our labels of "past" and "future", "yesterday" and "tomorrow" etc. Indeed, there are ways of stating the second law of thermodynamics that make no reference at all to time.

Note, however, that our memories and records of events *are* tied to the thermodynamic arrow of time. We can only remember or record events that are in the direction of decreasing entropy i.e. in what we conventionally call "the past".